# What claims are there on the word 'ale' other than for 'cask-brewed real ale'?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

The word *ale* has followed a movable pattern over the centuries, as the following extract from the OED will illustrate.

The enduring characteristic of the word is that it has been employed in opposition to *beer* to describe a more traditional variety. From the 15th century *ale* was beer that had not been brewed from hops, but from conventional malt.

But has it now reached the point where we have a settled definition? In other words, are there any claims on the word *ale* other than the *cask-brewed* *real ale*, sold on tap, with no added pressure? This is as opposed to mass-produced nitrogen or carbon-dioxide-added beer that is sold in cans and some bottles. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cask_ale

> With the introduction of regular use of hops into England from at
>   least the 15th cent., ale came to designate beer brewed without hops,
>   a distinction which lasted until the 18th cent., when it came to refer
>   to a strong beer. In the 19th cent. ale was sometimes distinguished by
>   its being brewed with malt that has not been roasted or burnt, and
>   hence being paler in colour. The word is now most common (outside
>   historical contexts) as a trade name, or (esp. in real ale, cask ale,
>   etc.) referring to traditionally brewed beer (of any colour).

Comment: 1) Beer brewed _with_ hops is not the same as beer brewed _from_ hops. Hops were added (afaik) as a preserving agent, but even when hops were added, malt was used as the basis for beer. 2) How about the (by now) countless varieties of _Indian Pale **Ale**_, the IPA that _most_ people know (as opposed to the International Phonetic Alphabet that is popular here or the IsoPropylic Alcohol popular in other areas).

Comment: As oerkelens' comment amply demonstrates, this Q rightly belongs on a food & beverage Q&A (for getting the right kind of answer). After all, dictionary editors get their inputs from domain experts, not from grammarians/ linguists (alone). Suggesting appropriate migration.

Comment: Also, the OP could (should?) have included what definitions various dictionaries offer today and the various other resources that may have traced the history of the word. Some research effort.

Comment: I am not convinced that the premise "The enduring characteristic of the word is that it has been employed in opposition to beer to describe a more traditional variety" is true. As far as I know, ales and lagers are the two main kinds of beer, so it is more of a sub-group than an opposition. The sub-group ale then splits into the brown ales (Newcastle Brown for example), pale ales  (IPA) and golden ales that seem to be popular at Christmas. There are other smaller groups too (for example, mild ale) - but all of them are beer.

Comment: @RoaringFish My Wiki link explains the essential difference between cask-produced ale, which is unfiltered and unpasteurised, from mass-produced ale with nitrogen/carbon dioxide added and contained in kegs, cans or bottles. A campaign over about three decades in Britain (known as the Campaign for Real Ale - CAMRA) eventually forced brewers to go back to the traditional method of 'home produced ale'. The result has been the arrival of thousands of small breweries each with its own delectable brands of *real ale*. But is beer produced in such fashion the only kind that is rightly called *ale*.

Comment: @Kris That is why I provided the definition of *ale* from the OED.

Comment: @WS2 ~ I am British, and very familiar with CAMRA. You link doesn't define ale, it defines real ale -v- mass produced ale. I know ales come in many colours which is why I mention 3 - brown, pale, and golden. However, lager and ale are definitely distinct - very distinct, brewed by distinct methods. CAMRA says so here -> http://www.camra.org.uk/faq, and also here -> http://www.beertutor.com/articles/ales_vs_lagers.shtml

Comment: @RoaringFish I hadn't realised that CAMRA had restricted the concept of *real ale* to non-lagers.  I think you (with the benefit of the CAMRA paper) have actually addressed the question I asked. Given that many of the German lagers are traditionally brewed, the way they have been for centuries, the term *ale* clearly still means something other than *real* brewing. May I suggest you post your comments and the sheet from CAMRA as an answer. So how then is the word *ale* defined. Do you take issue with the OED definition in my OP?

Comment: @RoaringFish Would it be correct, therefore, to say that *ale* is any 'top-fermented' beer - as opposed to 'bottom-fermented' *lager*'?. And *real ale* is any that is produced by the traditional process? It does mean, using that definition, that we have to accord the word *ale* to mass-produced swill than comes in cans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely a settled definition. According to [CAMRA](http://www.camra.org.uk/faq), the UK-based Campaign for Real Ale:

*Real ale is produced by ‘top fermentation' at  temperatures up to 22°C which produces the rich variety of flavours in an ale.*

This is contrasted with lager:

*Lager is produced by bottom fermentation at temperatures  6-14°C and then it should be conditioned for several weeks at about 0 – 1°C during which time the lager matures.*

This means that it is not so much a situation of ale being employed in opposition to beer, as ale being a sub-group of the generic term *beer*, with the other being lager and the two differentiated by the brewing process. Ale itself has more sub-groups, which CAMRA list as Mild, Bitter, Best Bitter, Porter, Stout, Barley Wines, and Golden Ales.

Comment: I have ticked as the 'correct' answer as it does correspond with the first definition in the OED which says ale is *any beer other than lager, stout or porter spec. beer brewed by top fermentation*. I was quite wrong in my comment that there was no distinction between ale and lager and I have deleted it. I was confused by the further indication in the OED that the word *ale* is nowadays *most common...in referring to traditionally brewed beer of whatever colour*. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the tick, but you should delete the apology too - it is not really needed. i suspect that in any given bar, very few drinkers would be able to define an ale. I know only because I take my beer very seriously, with a strong leaning towards dark ales. A good dark ale is heaven in a glass...

Comment: Do they have English ales in Bali?